# DataGridView в файл

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

Подскажите, как записать и считать строки dataGridView в уже созданный файл начиная со второй строки.

Comment: Как данные попадают в DataGridView - напрямую или через привязку данных?

Comment: Попадают напрямую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные в файле можно перезаписывать, то попробуйте так

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("filedg.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                sw.Write(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[j, i].Value));
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
        sw.Close();
```

Если же надо дописывать к уже имеющимся данным, то используйте `File.AppendText`